# C++ unknown to me construction in constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is this weird colon-member syntax in the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor)

Here is a sketch of the code. I do not understand this line - `Queue():first(0), last(0){}`.
What does `first(0)` mean. I know and understand the idea of queue. I have coded it many times, but don't know what that means in c++.

```
class Queue{
 struct Element{
    double val;
    Element* next;
 }*first, *last;

 void insert(double x);
 void get(double &x);
public:
    Queue():first(0), last(0){}

};
```

Comment: Okay, I'm having issues trying to close it, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor

Comment: And another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604176/strange-constructor

Answer (score 3):

It is an [initialization list](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html). It allows you constructing your member variables directly with the values you want to assign them, rather than default-constructing them and *then* assigning them in the body of your constructor.

Suppose you have a class `A` with a default constructor and a constructor accepting one argument:

```
struct A
{
    A() : n(0) { } // For scalar types, n = 0 in the constructor's body is equivalent
    A(int n) : n(a) { } // Should be marked as "explicit", but not relevant here
    int a;
};
```

And a class `X` with a member variable of type `A`. The constructor of `X` takes an argument of type `int` which needs to be assigned to `A`'s variable `a`. Without an initialization list, this is how you would do it:

```
struct X
{
    X(int n) { a.a = n; } // First invoke A::A(), then assign n to a.a
    A a;
};
```

But here you have **two** instructions rather than one: a (potentially expensive) default construction of your member variable `a`, followed by an assignment to change its state as desired. If you already know the arguments with which `a` should be constructed, it does not make sense to perform a default construction first just to override that initialization.

It must be said, though, that when initializing *scalar types* (as is the case of your example), the form based on initialization lists is equivalent to the one based on regular assignments in the constructor's body, since scalar types are *not* zero-initialized by default (more precisely, they are not initialized in any way).

---

As a related information, in an initialization list the name of your constructor's arguments won't hide the name of the member variables you want to construct:

```
struct X
{
    X(int a) : a(a) { } // OK (although I do not like it)
    int a;
};
```

In a regular assignment, on the contrary, `a` would be regarded to be the constructor's argument on both sides of the assignment:

```
struct X
{
    X(int a) { a = a; } // Self-assignment of the constructor's argument...
    int a;
};
```

This said, I do not consider a good practice to use identical names for member variables and function arguments. I mentioned it because it is good to be aware of this if you will have to read code written by others.

Comment: Could you give me equivalent of that in less shortcut way than shown in the example code.

Comment: Robert, a "less shortcut" (but *not* exactly equivalent under all cases) way to do that would be: `Queue() { first = 0; last = 0; }`

Comment: I find it worth making it clear that scalar types are not initialized period.

Comment: @chris: right, let me rephrase.

Answer (score 2):

This is a member initialization list. The line `Queue():first(0), last(0){}` defines a default constructor for `Queue` that initializes the `first` and `last` members to 0 and then does nothing else.

The members `first` and `last` are both of type `Element*` ("pointer to `Element`") and `0` is a null pointer constant. When initialised with `0`, `first` and `last` are null pointers.

Comment: But first and last are not ints or doubles, so how it can be initialized to 0?

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, since we're dealing with scalar types, it's equivalent to:

```
Queue()
{
    first = 0;
    last = 0;
}
```

Comment: but first and last are not numbers but objects

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at. `first` and `last` are pointers, and you can initialize pointers with the constant zero. Also, pointers *are* scalar types in C++.